# How to display a C++ char variable's memory address?

Tags: c++, variables, memory, char, memory-address

While practicing with C++, I tried to display a `char` variable's address with the `&` operator, but I see a meaningless line of characters instead of a memory address.

Below is the complete program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a;
    a = 'a';

    cout << &a;
}
```

Below is the output display I see:

[image: Memory address of a char variable in C++]

I have tried to search online to find a solution and detailed information about this issue, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: `&a` will return `char*` and `cout` thought you want to print a string that pointed by `&a`. So you could just cast it to `int` like this `cout << int(&a)`

Comment: There's an [`operator <<` overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for handling C strings. Just cast it to something else, like `static_cast<uintptr_t>(&a)`

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior due to using a non-null terminated character buffer to `cout`.

Comment: If you want to print a pointer, then print a pointer, don't cast it to an integer.  `operator<<` has an overload for `void*`, which all pointers are convertible to, eg: `cout << static_cast<void*>(&a)`

Comment: The output you see was caused by your IDE filling the memory with `0xCC `in debug builds as a debug aide. Remember to recognize this symbol: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892)

Answer (score 3):

A pointer to a character - `char *` - is treated as a pointer to a C-style string, and printed as if it were one, even though it isn't in your program: a C-style string is an array of characters and then a terminating NUL byte. Because that NUL byte is not there, meaningless garbage is printed.

C-style strings predate C++ and `<iostream>`, but they are still a part of the language; string literals like `"hello"` are also C-style strings, for example.

If you want to print the address, one way is to cast the pointer to `void *`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char a;
    a = 'a';

    cout << static_cast<void *>(&a);
}
```

That way, you get the overload of `operator<<` that can print any kind of pointer as its memory address, not the overload of `operator<<` that prints C-style strings.

Comment: Minor point: `char *` is treated as a **pointer to** a C-style string. A C-style string is a nul-terminated **array** of `char`. +1.

Comment: "*Because that NUL byte is not there, meaningless garbage is printed*" - that is one possible outcome.  Technically, the behavior of printing a null-terminated string without a null terminator is *undefined*, so literally anything could happen. You could print garbage. You could crash the app. You could trash memory. And so on.

Comment: I am confused about the "pointer" part. What I understand is that I create a char variable, not a char pointer. And the "&" symbol is being called as "the address-of operator" in all sources I read. So, if I create an integer, int a, I get the memory address of the variable by displaying &a. Why doesn't it work with a char variable the same way?

Comment: &a is a pointer to a, which makes it's type `char *`. cout has a specific overload for `char *`

Comment: Autocorrect  inserted the wrong its.